# Java Exception handling looping error

Tags: java

**I FIGURED EVERYTHING OUT TY FOR THE HELP**

When I type in letters at attempt 1/4 it works fine and it continues, but once I type a letter at attempt 2/4 it just prints the message and the program stops. Also any tips on #2, I can only think of if(guess>=4 && guess<=16) else statement(not sure if this is correct)

When I execute the code -

```
Guess a number between 1 and 16.

Attempt 1 of 4: 8

You guessed 8

Too Low! 

Attempt 2 of 4: a

Please enter an integer between 4-16
```

**can't enter anything after**

Problems: I have to make exception handlers if user types in a

1) non-numeric input

2) out of range input

3) Have to retain current guess amount

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

static final int limit = 4;
static final int maxInteger = 16;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Random rand = new Random();
int target = rand.nextInt(maxInteger) + 1;
int x = 1;

    do{
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Guess a number between 1 and %d.\n", maxInteger);


    int attempts = 1;
    while (attempts <= limit) {
        System.out.printf("Attempt %d of %d: ", attempts, limit);


        int guess = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("You guessed %d\n", guess);

        if(guess > target) {
        System.out.printf("Too High! \n");

        }
        else if(guess == target){

        System.out.printf("The answer is %d, You win!", guess);
            attempts = 20;

        }
        else{
        System.out.printf("Too Low! \n");

        }

        attempts+=1;
        x = 2;
    }
    if(attempts==5){
    System.out.println("You lose!");
    }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.printf("Please enter an integer between 4-16");
        continue;


    }
    }while(x == 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include the error trace?

Comment: what is your problem? You want to know how to write a new exception or that your exception is not caught?

Comment: added what happens when I execute the program at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking `while(x == 1);` in the outer loop and from the inner loop you incremented the value of `x` by doing `x = 2;`. This will break the condition and you'll come out of the outer `while` loop.

You should be setting a valid condition for the outer `while` loop if you want to continue. Try something like `while(x < 5);`

Your code should look something like this:

```
do {
    try {
        ...
        /* Inner While */
        while() {}
        ...
    } catch () {
        /* Exception Handling */
        ...
    }
} while(x < 5); /* Decide a valid condition */
```

Comment: I changed x = 2; into x++; and while(x < 5); My attempts reset to 1/4 if I type a letter in 2/4 but I want it to stay as 2/4, 3/4 , 4/4 their current attempts. and it doesn't execute the "You lose" in this scenario. Results now when I execute it. http://pastebin.com/5W1NwDuU

Comment: It is because you are initializing your `attempts` inside the `do-while`. You should declare it outside the `do-while` loop.

Comment: You have only one `do-while` loop. The other `while` is inside this `do-while` loop.

Comment: Couple of changes. Please change the class Name. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/KZWfvNbr

Comment: ty for help, I solved the problem. 2nd answer helped more but I guessing x and the boolean flag could be considered the same thing.

Comment: Didn't even see your edited code pastebin, was looking at what's wrong with my code before. Thought you left forever.

Comment: I tried to copy/paste your code but I get some package error. Is that code the solution?

Comment: Actually, didn't see you gave me the attempt help. You both gave me like equal amount of help. But, I'll give you the check since it seems like you care about it and the other guy doesn't(amounts of answers). Also you replied so I guess you tried harder.

Answer (score 1):

1) try moving your try catch block inside the inner loop so it only encloses

```
int guess = input.nextInt();
```

2) your idea for number 2 should work.

```
if(guess>=4 && guess<=16)
```

make sure this is the first if statement in your checks, then you don't have to change any of your other if statements.

3) make a variable outside both of the loops called guess, then instead of saying

```
int guess = input.nextInt();
```

just say

```
guess = input.nextInt();
```

The current guess wil be availble to you until you update it.

4) your variable x is confusing. Are you using it as a flag to end the outer loop? if that is the case make it a boolean

```
boolean flag = true;
```

then you can set the flag to false when you are ready to break out of the loop. change

```
x = 2;
```

to

```
flag = false;
```

also for the loop all change

```
while(x==1)
```

to

```
while(flag)
```